# text not showing on Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue getting text to show on Tkinter buttons. I don't get any errors so im not sure why this is the case, I will post the full working code below if anyone can see any obvius errors.I have never had any problems with button labels before but I am trying a new layout with dropdown tabs so this could be a reason for the issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 


class ToggledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, text="", *args, **options):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **options)
        root.state('zoomed')
        root.configure(background='black')
        root.title("Stylibleue dashboard")
        self.show = tk.IntVar()
        self.show.set(0)

        self.title_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.title_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)

        ttk.Label(self.title_frame, text=text).pack(side="left", fill="x")


        self.toggle_button = ttk.Checkbutton(self.title_frame, width=1, text='+', 
        command=self.toggle,
                                        variable=self.show, style='Toolbutton')
        self.toggle_button.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=1)

        self.sub_frame = tk.Frame(self, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1)

    def toggle(self):
        if bool(self.show.get()):
            self.sub_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            self.toggle_button.configure(text='-')
        else:
            self.sub_frame.forget()
            self.toggle_button.configure(text='+')


    def helloCallBack (self):
        print ("hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()



    t = ToggledFrame(root, text='Bassin 1', relief="raised")
    t.pack(fill="x", anchor="s")


    B = ttk.Button(t.sub_frame, text ='Feeder 1',command = quit)
    ttk.Button(t.sub_frame).pack( expand=0, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="w")

    c = ttk.Button(t.sub_frame, text ="Feeder 2")
    ttk.Button(t.sub_frame).pack(expand=0, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="w")




    t2 = ToggledFrame(root, text='Bassin 2', relief="raised")
    t2.pack(fill="x")

    d = ttk.Button(t2.sub_frame, text ='Feeder 1',command = quit)
    ttk.Button(t2.sub_frame).pack( expand=0, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="w")

    e = ttk.Button(t2.sub_frame, text ="Feeder 2")
    ttk.Button(t2.sub_frame).pack(expand=0, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="w")


    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 8 buttons but only giving a label to four of them, and it’s the ones without a label that you are calling `.pack` on. The ones with the label are never added to the window.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Should I delete this post? I don't think it will help anyone else as it was a simple mistake.